# Bug about UIImageView display gif?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, gif, sdwebimage

I create a UIImageView and add to VC UIView , then I create a image with `animatedImageWithImages:duration:`

When I execute the code, it works normally. It displays image animation. But when I push to next VC and  in the process of swipe back , I find the UIImageView display nothing.
At the moment finger left screen , everything back to normal.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];               
     UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
     imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
     imgView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 80, 80);
     [self.view addSubview:imgView];     
     NSArray *imgs = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"]];
     imgView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:imgs duration:0.5];
}
```

[BugGif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46F4c.gif)

I notice the imageView has CAKeyframeAnimation. I guess the conflict that runmode and CAKeyframeAnimation.

SDWebImage has the same problem. Because it also use the method that create UIImage. I think the point is the method of animatedImageWithImages:duration: and CAKeyframeAnimation.

Anyone knows the solution? Thanks a lot.

The event that the finger left the screen will make imageView display normally. Why and How to resolve?

[GitHubBugDemo](https://github.com/EverMe/TestImgBug)

Comment: have you tried it on viewWillAppear ??

Comment: Try loading the image in viewWillAppear delegate & this will be solved.

Comment: it doesn't work.  viewWillAppear have run, but display nothing util the finger left screen. I think the point is what happen in the moment  the finger left screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImageView another methods to set images and animation duration as below

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 80, 80);
NSArray *imgs = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2"]];
[imgView setAnimationImages:imgs];
[imgView setAnimationDuration:1];
[imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VAL];
[imgView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: it doesn't work. when I push to next VC and in the process of swipe back , the UIImageView display nothing and never return to normal even the finger left screen.

Comment: Just declare imageView object in .h file and call this method  [imgView startAnimating]; on view will appear

Comment: I have tried , but it's failed.  [This is the bug demo](https://github.com/EverMe/TestImgBug) only a few lines of code.